# What is the relation?

Tags: integration

The function $x^2 = y\quad$ limits two areas $A$ and $B$:

$A$ is further limited with the line $x= a$, $a\gt 0$.
$A$ rotates around the $x$-axis, which gives Volume $A = Va$.

$B$ is limited with the line $y=b$, $b\gt 0$.
$B$ rotates around the $y$-axis, which gives Volume $B = Vb$.

What are the relations between $a$ and $b$, when $Vb = Va$?

..................

I have come to the solution that:

$Vb = (\pi b^2 )/ 2$

$Va = (\pi a^5) / 5$

so the relation between them is:

$2.5b^2 = a^5$

Is that the final solution or is it more?

Answer (score 1):

If your calculations are correct this is what you should have found.

Comment: Its homework right?

Comment: I was thinking maybe a simplification of my answer?

Comment: No i've got my final exam on monday, so was thinking of training on old exams and other diverse stuff.

Comment: Unless stated in the question that you have to produce some special answer, your answer should be excepted. Good luck on your test.

Comment: No it just says, what are the relations between a and b. when Va=Vb! Thank you Tau!

Answer (score 1):

Without a drawing or a more detailed description, I cannot be certain.  But under the reasonable interpretation of what you wrote, your conclusion is absolutely correct.  Maybe, since $a$ and $b$ are positive, it might be slightly better to say that
$$b=a^2\sqrt{\frac{2a}{5}}$$

Comment: Who did you get your solution?

Comment: @aka: I am not sure of the meaning of your question.  I drew the parabola, decided what the regions $A$ and $B$ were supposed to be, calculated the volumes of the solids, in each case by slicing, so for $A$ I integrated with respect to $x$ and for $B$ with respect to $y$.  The integrations were trivial, as you discovered.

Comment: The solution given above by user6312 is a *simplification* of your solution, in terms of expressing the relation b as a function of a: multiply both sides of your solution by 2/5 (the reciprocal of 2.5 = 5/2), then take the square root of both sides.

Comment: I'm sorry i mean, how* !

Comment: @aka: I tried to describe it briefly in a comment above.  I drew the diagram, and then calculated as explained in the very detailed explanation by @Arturo Magidin.  I quickly obtained the expressions you wrote down, so took it for granted that you had done it the same way, so that a detailed working out of the details was not needed by you.  Wrote down an alternate formula expressing $b$ in terms of $a$, in case you met this sort of question in a multiple choice test.

Comment: I wish it was a multiple choice test... they want calculations! But many thanks for your help Both User6312 and Arturo!

Answer (score 1):

If we take the region bounded by the $y$-axis, the $x$-axis, the line $x=a$ (with $a\gt 0$), and the parabola $y=x^2$, and rotate it about the $x$-axis, the volume of the resulting solid of revolution is easily computed (using, for example, discs perpendicular to the $x$-axis) to be
$$\text{Volume A} = \int_0^a \pi(x^2)^2\,dx = \frac{\pi}{5}x^5\Bigm|_0^a = \frac{\pi a^5}{5}.$$
If the region bounded by the $y$-axis, the $x$ axis, the line $y=b$ (with $b\gt 0$), and the parabola $y=x^2$ is revolved around the $y$-axis, then using discs perpendicular to the $y$-axis we obtain the volume to be:
$$\text{Volume B} = \int_0^b \pi (\sqrt{y})^2\,dy = \frac{\pi}{2}y^2\Bigm|_0^b = \frac{\pi b^2}{2}.$$
So your computations are correct there.

If the two volumes are the same, then we must have
$$\text{Volume A} = \frac{\pi a^5}{5} = \frac{\pi b^2}{2} = \text{Volume B};$$
there are many ways to express this: you can solve for one of $a$ or $b$ in terms of the other:
$$b = \sqrt{\frac{2a^5}{5}} = a^{5/2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}},$$
or, if you want to express $a$ in terms of $b$ instead,
$$ a = \sqrt[5]{\frac{5}{2}b^2} = b^{2/5}\sqrt[5]{\frac{5}{2}}.$$
Or you can simply express this relation by saying, say
$$2a^5 = 5b^2.$$

**Note.** If $a\lt 0$, then the volume of $A$ can be computed the same way, but the integral would go from $a$ to $0$, so that the volume would be $-\frac{\pi a^5}{5}$; to account for both possibilities, both $a\gt 0$ and $a\lt 0$, you can simply write that the volume is $\frac{\pi|a|^5}{5}$. For solid $B$, however, it makes no sense to talk about $b\lt 0$, because then we don't have a finite area "enclosed" by the curves in question.

Comment: I did exacly the same calculations, was just a bit confused by the simplification you made in the last steps... but i think it is as you say...

 2a^5 = 5b^2
 2a^5/5 = b^2
then take square root we get:

sqroot ((2a^5)/5) = b
b = a^2* sqroot(2a/5)

if we want a:
a^5 = (5b^2/2)
a = 5root(5b^2/2)
a = b^(2/5) * 5root(5/2)